# KeyListener not getting to keyPressed method

Tags: java

Currently attempting to make a little game and i'm having a problem with moving the cube I have made, went through debugging and when i'm pressing w,a,s or d it is not moving to the keyPressed method, i'm also having a problem when my application opens the buttons I have placed in don't appear until I hover over them and also my JTextField doesn't show up at all, help would be much appreciated

```
public class littlegame extends JFrame implements ActionListener, WindowListener, KeyListener {

Color color_grey = new Color (188, 188, 188);

JButton btn_Quit, btn_Menu;

int charx = 200;
int chary = 200;

private Rectangle rect;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    littlegame littleGame = new littlegame();
    littleGame.runapplication();
}

private void runapplication() {

    setSize(1600,800);
    setLocation(50,50);
    setTitle("Little Game");
    setResizable(false);

    this.addKeyListener(this);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
    setLayout(springLayout);

    JButtons(springLayout);
    JTextFields(springLayout);
    rect = new Rectangle(200,200,50,50);

    setVisible(true);

}

private void JButtons(SpringLayout layout)  {

    btn_Menu = new JButton ("Menu");
    this.add(btn_Menu);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, btn_Menu, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, btn_Menu, 15, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
    btn_Menu.addActionListener(this);

    btn_Quit = new JButton ("Quit");
    this.add(btn_Quit);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, btn_Quit, 1525, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, btn_Quit, 15, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
    btn_Quit.addActionListener(this);
}

private void JButtonMethod(SpringLayout layout)    {


}

private void JTextFields(SpringLayout layout)   {

    JTextField txt_Menu_Background = new JTextField ();
    this.add(txt_Menu_Background);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, txt_Menu_Background, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, txt_Menu_Background, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
    txt_Menu_Background.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1600, 50));
    txt_Menu_Background.setEditable(false);
    txt_Menu_Background.setBackground(color_grey);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.fill(rect);


}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == btn_Quit)   {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}


public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {

}


public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

}


public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {

}


public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {

}


public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {

}


public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {

}


public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)    {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y + 5);
    }

    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)   {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x - 5, rect.y);
    }

    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D)   {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x + 5, rect.y);
    }

    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)   {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y - 5);
    }

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the focus when you press the key?

Answer (score 0):

Swing should run in its own "event dispatch thread".

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Answer (score 0):

The KeyListener events are being intercepted by the Swing components, and not being passed on to your listener.

The simplest solution is to no combine Swing components and your own "GUI" code; use either one or the other.